# Rails 4 not using form method PATCH, defaulting to POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following line which generates a form tag;

```
<%= form_for :stream, url: stream_path(@stream), method: :patch do |f| %>
```

It generates the following;

```
<form method="post" action="/streams/52b02d267e3be39d3da5aa609f1049d7" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

If I change it to `:put` it still has it has post but if I write `method: :get` it *will* change it to `get`

Does anyone have any idea why it would be doing this and what I can do to prevent it?

Here is the output from rake routes;

```
    Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                 Controller#Action
    streams GET   /streams(.:format)          streams#index
           POST   /streams(.:format)          streams#create
 new_stream GET   /streams/new(.:format)      streams#new
edit_stream GET   /streams/:id/edit(.:format) streams#edit
     stream GET   /streams/:id(.:format)      streams#show
          PATCH   /streams/:id(.:format)      streams#update
            PUT   /streams/:id(.:format)      streams#update
         DELETE   /streams/:id(.:format)      streams#destroy
```

The background is this is a simple edit form, all I want it to do is his the update method of the controller.

## Follow up

In my layout file I am bringing in csrf_meta_tags and my `javascript_include_tag` links to a file called "stream" which has the following

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Comment: [Toby](http://stackoverflow.com/users/197302/toby) do you want to mark [Alejandro's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2325440/alejandro-silva) answer as correct?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
method: (:get|:post|:patch|:put|:delete)
```

from the documentation:

> "in the options hash. If the verb is not GET or POST, which are natively supported by HTML forms, the form will be set to POST and a hidden input called _method will carry the intended verb for the server to interpret."

source: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html

Answer (score 0):

is `//= require jquery_ujs` in your application.js?

also make sure

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application"%>
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

are present in your layout file.

Comment: Good question - I am including my own which has //=require jquery and //= require jquery_ujs (and nothing else)

Comment: can you make sure if jquery_ujs is being loaded by checking in page source? :)

Comment: I can see it is being loaded in fine in the source and there are no errors in the console.

Comment: try url: streams_path(@stream) instead of stream_path

Comment: if everything is fine it will pass and hidden field
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" /> along with form because as per my knowledge other than get,post rest is handled by jquery_ujs file.